# View not displayed for other roles

Tags: 7, views, nodes, panels

I have a block view that displays own articles created (this view is inside a panel page). But this view didn't displayed for other users except administrators, or when I check the permission 'Bypass content access control' to the other roles.

You know that this permission is a risk when it's checked, and I won't that other users have access to everything for nodes.

I checked the permissions like that :

- inside the Views UI edit page : access option => View published content (I changed to 'none' also)
- inside user permission page : "View published content" && "View own unpublished content" of "node" section are checked (also other permissions : create new article, edit own article ...)
- there is no restriction in the block settings for a specific role.

Is really weird what happen here.
doese anyone have this problem before? Or how you can advise me to resolve this permission issue?

Thanks in advance.

**ADD:**

this is a list of modules in the website:[image]

**EDIT**

I found from where is this problem :
my articles are not yet published and only published articles are shown in the view content. I made sure that the permission "view own unpublished content" is checked, but content still not shown when i unpublish again the articles (views content is not shown to the AUTHOR of these nodes)

I found this [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) to grant users to see all unpublished content but this is not good for me, because i need users to see only their content.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are there ANY other permissions modules on the site? are you sure the user has access to view the contents of the block - ie if the problem isn't the block itself but that the user doesn't have permission to see the Views contents, it won't show since Views respects access restrictions

Comment: Did you check the `Show block for specific roles` in block configuration page?

Comment: @Geoff where can I find the permission to allow users to see views content? Inside permission page there are two permissions related to views for administer views only and not to show content of views. Also inside the view itself there is an option for access that I disabled it, so anyone can access to this view. I checked as well all other modules permission one by one there is nothing related to content view. But when I check "Bypass content access control" the view shown for that role!

Comment: @drupalist Yes like described in the question I checked the block configuration as well inside block configuration.

Comment: My comment wasn't that the user might not be able to see the view, but the actual content being represented by the View. If you have a module like Field Permissions, Node Access, etc, they could be restricting what the user sees in the View

Comment: I edited the post to add a list of used modules.

Comment: I've found it useful in the past to check all instances of ''access callback' and 'access arguments' in modules.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the permission "view own unpublished content". Even this permission is checked, author of articles can't see his own unpublished articles!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you haven't configured the contextual filter on author_id in views. and take it for logged users. In that case it will show the other users pages aswell

Comment: I made a Relationship with author, then in filter criteria I added filter with current logged in user (using this relationship).

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off rewriting sql and make conditionals on your own in the view. Then relationship to author_id will show you nodes which he saved in the system.

Turning off rewriting for this block will turn off node_access check.